# Cloud watch metric alert suppression if threshold breaching often

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have configured cloud watch alert based on alert metric that matches  pattern and triggers alert once threshold is breached,I am looking for way that alert is not sent again if that alert pattern is matching after it has notified once to avoid sending notification on the same error.

Comment: The question is not clear at all.

Comment: If cloud watch metric picks up error pattern it will trigger alarm,now if that pattern is coming frequently alerts will keep coming to SNS,how to change the behaviour after 1 alert that it doesn’t generate alert for next couple of hours  if that error string is repeating.

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems not possible with cloudwatch. Maybe you can create a script which creates cloudwatch alarm using cli and not console and remove the alarm when you get an sns and then check the pattern and decide if to create the alarm again or not.